# How best to handle relative urls in scraped content?

Tags: javascript, python, html

What are some methods to make relative urls absolute in scraped content so that the scraped html appears like the original and css are not broken?

I found out `<base>` tag may help. But how can I find out what the original base of the URL is?

I don't care about interactions with the links, but do want them to appear correct.

Assume a site 'example.com/blog/new/i.html' i scrape that has 2 resources

1. < link src="/style/style.css" >
2. < link src="newstyle.css" >.

Now if i set base as 'example.com/blog/new/i.html' wont the first one break

Comment: You are scraping the content so it should be pretty easy for you to know what the base url should be.

Comment: is base same as the scrapped url??

Comment: You're the webdeveloper here. What do you think a relative URL means ;-)

Comment: When you "found out `<base>` tag may help", what exactly did you find out? I can't imagine where you would learn anything useful without learning the whole answer.

Comment: This post is old But just for clarification 
Assume a site 'example.com/blog/new/i.html' i scrape that has 2 resources 1. <link src="/style/style.css" > another <link src="newstyle.css">. Now if i set base as 'example.com/blog/new/i.html' wont the first one break

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the url of each page you scraped. One way would be to save it with the full URL as a filename. Then, you can resolve relative urls as per the HTML spec.

Comment: just for clarification Assume a site 'example.com/blog/new/i.html' i scrape that has 2 resources 1. <link src="/style/style.css" > 2. <link src="newstyle.css">. Now if i set base as 'example.com/blog/new/i.html' wont the first one break

Answer (score 0):

Can't say about JS, but I can tell you how to do it in **Python using BeautifulSoup** or any other html parsing library.

1. Find the tags
2. Check for relative urls
3. Replace them with
   base_url+relative_url
4. Page ready for viewing

---

```
base_url = 'http://www.Python-The-Bagpiper.com'

content = urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
img_tags = soup.findAll('img')
link_tags = soup.findAll('link')
a_tags = soup.findAll('a')
#add any other tag with links


for tags in img_tags + link_tags + a_tags:

    attr_name = 'src' if tag.get('src') else 'href' if tag.get('href') else None
    url = tag.get(attr_name)

    if url and 'http://' not in url and url[0] is not '#':
        fullurl = base_url + url
        tag[attr_name] = fullurl

print soup.prettify
```